# How can I parse a vector to a bool in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector, boolean

I'm trying to write a program that first checks if a name is in a vector and if not then adds it to the vector. My code seems to have difficulties with parsing, at least that's what I get out of it. I tried changing the string to a char but it did not help me much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

bool isinVector(std::string uElement, std::vector<std::string> uArray)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= sizeof(uArray); i++) {
        if (uArray[i] == uElement) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool trigger = false;
    while (!trigger) {
        std::vector<std::string> names;
        names.push_back("Bart");
        std::string newName;
        getline(std::cin, newName);
        if (isinVector(newName, names))
        {
            std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
            trigger = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
            names.push_back(newName);
            for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(names); i++) {
                std::cout << names[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be clear about what exactly you need help with. This is quite vague right now.

Comment: Please make the title relevant to the problem you are having not just "please help me". Which part of your code goes wrong? Please narrow it down to that.

Comment: `sizeof(uArray)` does not give you the size of `uArray`. Use `uArray.size()` instead.

Comment: `sizeof` does not mean what you think it means, and you have not seen it used with vectors in any example.

Answer (score 3):

I made some adjustments to your code, removing your isinVector function and using a lambda inside the main function instead. In the future please provide a concise question and example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::find_if;

int main(){
    bool trigger = false;
    while (!trigger) {

        vector<string> names;

        names.push_back("Bart");

        string newName;

        getline(cin, newName);

        if(find_if(names.begin(), names.end(), [newName] (const string& name){

            return !name.compare(newName);

        }) != names.end()){

            cout << "true" << endl;
            trigger = true;

        }

        else{

            cout << "false" << endl;
            names.push_back(newName);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {

                cout << names.at(i) << endl;

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code uses std::find_if to check if the element exists in the vector. If `std::find_f` does not return the iterator to `uArray.end()` Then the element exists. Also your for loop used sizeof which is incorrect, use the vector.size method. And you were looping until `<=` , it should be `< uArray.size()` And it's safer to access elements in the vector through the .at method rather than an index `[]` since the .at will throw an out_of_range exception.

Comment: Thank you, I will take more care putting down my example code next time!

Comment: If you have decided to change the syntax to +11 I would add lambda expression inside the main function and write auto instead of iterator type. OP is probably not familiar with +03/+11 syntax and explaining your change would help him

Comment: Okay, I'll make the adjustments.

Comment: "it's safer to access elements in the vector through the .at method rather than an index []" - Sure, but when you *know* that the index is within bounds, `.at()` just adds unnecessary overhead that the compiler cannot remove for you.

Comment: Yes @JesperJuhl that is true. Ideally, indexing or .at should not be called if the developer doesn't know the bounds of the vector. Which they should always know. I can see some cases where in a multithreaded application the vector is being altered and the developer at the specific time might not know the size. But in that case, thread locking can be used. In a single threaded application I don't believe I've ran into a situation where I did not know the bounds of my own vector.

Answer (score 1):

Among the things wrong in the updated post.

1. Improper use of `sizeof`
2. Reinventing a standard algorithm
3. Lack of error checking

Consider the tasks you're trying to accomplish. You want to:

1. Initialize a starting vector containing the name Bart
2. Continuously read new names. For each new name read:

   a. Check to see if it is already in the vector.

   - if it is present terminate the read loop
   - else add it to the vector, and print the entire vector

This sequence of operations can be accomplished with stepwise refinement.

---

**Step 1. Read names**

First, you need to be able to continuously read names:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, name))
        std::cout << name << '\n';
}
```

Simple enough. Running this will echo any strings you type, one at a time, separated by newlines.

**Step 2. Accumulate names in a vector**

Next, we need to add a vector to hold the strings we're reading, with an initial population of the name "Bart". For this pass we'll be just putting every string we read into the vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names = { "Bart" };

    std::string name;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, name))
    {
        names.emplace_back(name);
        for (auto const& s : names)
            std::cout << s << ' ';
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
}
```

In addition to what was done prior, we're now accumulating strings in the vector, including duplicates, and reporting the vector content after each name read. This gets us closer to our stated goal.

**Step 3: Conditional loop exit based on duplicate detection**

Now we need to check for duplicates, and terminate the loop once it happens. We can do this using [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). The final code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names = { "Bart" };

    std::string name;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, name))
    {
        if (std::find(names.begin(), names.end(), name) != names.end())
            break;

        names.emplace_back(name);
        for (auto const& s : names)
            std::cout << s << ' ';
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
}
```

That's it. This is a simple task, but it lends itself nicely to an example of how you break a multi-part task down to manageable objectives , then build it in pieces.

Hope you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Now my code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>



bool isinVector (std::string uElement, std::vector<std::string> uArray) {
    bool invector = false;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = std::find(uArray.begin(), 
    uArray.end(),uElement);
    if(it != uArray.end()){
        invector = true;
    }
    return invector;
}


int main(){
    bool trigger = false;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> names = { "Bart" };
    while (std::getline(std::cin, name)){
        if (isinVector(name, names)) {
            std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
            names.emplace_back(name);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it works, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: I did make further adjustments to the code that I initially posted if you want to look at that. Also look at @WhozCraig post, there's useful information in there as well.